# Piece of code to ensure site cannot be migrated from host?

Tags: security, wordpress, locking, migration, hosting

*Please note, my intention here is **not** malicious.  My intentions stem from contractual issues between myself and a client that I am working to enforce.*

Is there anything I can do - via PHP, .htaccess, MySQL or otherwise - that will ensure (to a decent extent) that a WordPress site would be difficult to migrate to a different host?

I completely understand that someone extremely well-versed in PHP, MySQL and WordPress might be able to find a workaround, but I need an easy solution that will ensure a client cannot zip up his WordPress app via FTP, export the database, and migrate it to a new host.

Restricting access to the MySQL admin and the root FTP is not an option.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

Really securely - no. As you say, anyone a bit versed in PHP can work around most restrictions.

Halfway decently, impossible for a not-well-versed person to work around - kind of. You'd need to identify some parameter that is going to change if servers are switched - for example, the directory structure, or the server's IP, which is in the `$_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]` variable.

There are other variables and parameters as well - do a `phpinfo()` to get an overview.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to know the value of $_ENV['HOSTNAME'] on your current server, but once you know this (and can verify it's not going to change obviously) you could edit the wp-blog-header.php file with the following on line 7:

```
if ($_ENV['HOSTNAME'] != 'your-host-name') {
    wp_die('Message to Display', 'Title of Error');
}
```

The reason I state to do this in wp-blog-header.php is because if I were going to look on how to fix this, I would look in index.php or the theme files.